# Laravel DB query with filtering from another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

At the moment in one of my controllers, I have the following query:

```php
$maintenances = DB::table("equipment_attachments")
                ->select(DB::raw('year(date) as year'), DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
                ->where('attachmentCategory','Maintenance')
                ->orderBy(DB::raw("year(date)"))
                ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(date)"))
                ->get();
```

And this works alright, but I'd like to filter it down even more, and I believe I know how to do this through models, but not quite sure with using the DB functions.

What I would like to be able to do is use another table called `equipment` and use a field called `type` to filter down to those with a type of only 3.

So basically I'd like to filter down from what is above but then proceed to use the field in the table `equipment_attachments` to where the equipment referenced in the field `equipment_attachments.unitID` is equal to a `equipment` where the `equipment.type` field is equal to 3.

Comment: Could try a [`join()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `join` and the use a `where` clause. your final query would look something like this.

```
DB::table("equipment_attachments") 
    ->join('equipments', 'equipments.id' , '=', 'equipment_attachments.unitID'
    ->select(DB::raw('year(date) as year'), DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count")) 
    ->where('attachmentCategory','Maintenance') 
    ->where('equipments.type', 3)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("year(date)")) 
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(date)")) 
    ->get();
```

Also you can simply use `selectRaw` to select using SQL functions.

```
   DB::table("equipment_attachments") 
    ->join('equipments', 'equipments.id' , '=', 'equipment_attachments.unitID'
    ->selectRaw("year(date) as year, COUNT(*) as count") 
    ->where('attachmentCategory','Maintenance') 
    ->where('equipments.type', 3)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("year(date)")) 
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(date)")) 
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options;

1. If you're using the query builder i.e. DB::query() then you'll need to join on the relevant tables and apply a where clause in that way.

[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

```
    $equipment = DB::table('equipment_attachments')
            ->join('equipment', 'equipment.id', '=', 'equipment_attachments.equipment_id')
            ->where('type', 3)
            ->select('equipment_attachments.*')
            ->get();
```

2. If you're using the eloquent ORM then you can use a whereHas() statement, but you'll need to define the relationship within the model first.

[Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

```
    EquipmentAttachment::whereHas('equipment', function($query) {
         $query->where('type', 3);
    })->all();
```

Personally, I would look at using the ORM as technically you wouldn't need to do any raw SQL meaning you can swap DB language easier if you wanted. I'm not sure on your date format in the DB, but if it's a timestamp you could achieve the same in the ORM with;

```
    EquipmentAttachment::where('date', (new DateTime())->format('Y')->all();
```

Finally, if you take of the first(), get() or all() you can put ->toSql() and the SQL statement can be echoed out, for example;

```
    echo EquipmentAttachment::where('date', '2018-06-14')->toSql();
    dd();
```

Hope that helps a little.